# Reducing If statements in C

Tags: c, optimization, if-statement

I was trying to count how many out of my four variables were greater than 0, so I wrote these if statements to achieve my purpose. All numbers will be positive or 0:

```
            if(a1>0){counter++;}
            if(a2>0){counter++;}
            if(a3>0){counter++;}
            if(a4>0){counter++;}

            printf("%d", counter);
```

It's quite obvious that I would run into some trouble if the number of variables were to increase. Is there a more efficient way of writing this?

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Without further information that is "as efficient" as it can be made. The names of the variables hints at something *else* in the code that could be altered...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a single statement,

```
 counter+= (a1>0) + (a2>0) + (a3>0) + (a4>0);
```

Should do. If you decide to pack your data into an array,

```
#define SIZE(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof*(x))
int x, a[4];
for(x=0; x<SIZE(a); x++)
    counter += (a[x]>0);
```

Is still reasonably compact.

Comment: Wow. I haven't seen this type of statement. It works, but I have no idea why :P 

Do you mind explaining what kind of magic this is?

Comment: It's because C defines the result of any true boolean expression to be 1, and the result of any false boolean expression to be 0.  Elegant solution.  Still, it suffers from the "if I have lots of local variables, my counter logic gets longer and longer" issue.  Much more compact than the OP's original solution though.

Comment: I think the array part takes care of that issue. Looks like the edit happened after your comment, @Eric J.

Comment: If you wanted to get more efficient for iterating through the array, you can do something called loop unfolding! I think you should be able to find what that is with a quick google search.

Comment: @JisBen loop *unrolling* isn't always more efficient. In fact, it can be less efficient because of cache effects. It's best to let the compiler make that decision.

Comment: If you know the specifics of the chip architecture, then you can almost always do better than the generic compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally you have to tell the compiler which memory address to check, and where to put the result.

If you have lots of local variables, you probably want to consider an array or similar data structure to hold them rather than tons of separately declared variables.  In that case, you could define an array to hold the counter results too, and use a loop construct.

If you do not have tons of local variables, I suspect your current approach is about as good as it gets (you could get fancy by placing a pointer to each variable in an array and then using a loop, but the array initialization would be at least as cumbersome as the current `if` statements).

I would not change your program logic to use arrays if named, individual variables are a more natural fit.

Answer (score 3):

What if you just used an array? such as this:

```
int a[4];
int counter;
int i; // iterator
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(a[i]>0){
        counter++;
    }
}
printf("%d", counter);
```

that would be faster, shorter code, but your way is efficient as possible if you must have separate variables.

Comment: Yes, but the counting is presumably only part of the programming task.    He's asking about how to check the state of a routine that I suppose is supposed to do an undefined (to us) useful task.  An array may or may not be a more natural fit for the primary task.  Not saying your answer is a bad one, just saying it depends on the primary purpose of the routine.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array rather than separate variables. Then just loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

If all variables are of the same type, you can store pointers to them in a array and use a loop to check and increment the counter.

Comment: Yes, but setting up the pointers will not be (much) shorter than the existing code and is less straightforward for someone else to understand in the future.